# QEMU can not mount cifs share but able to access files on cifs share

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, cifs

I have a cifs shared file system mounted at /var/lib/nasvirt as below.

`/mynas/vms on /var/lib/nasvirt type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=default,cache=strict,username=admin,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.x,file_mode=0755,dir_mo de=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)`

I can navigate to that directory as root or myself and create and edit a text file.

However when I try to create a qemu disk image to that location I get an input/ output failure and a 0 byte file.

```
root@host:~# qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/nasvirt/rtr2.cow 8G
Formatting '/var/lib/nasvirt/rtr2.cow', fmt=qcow2 size=8589934592 cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
qemu-img: /var/lib/nasvirt/rtr2.cow: Could not write qcow2 header: Input/output error
```

Creating the image locally works fine:

```
root@host:/# qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/rtr2.cow 8G
Formatting '/var/lib/libvirt/images/rtr2.cow', fmt=qcow2 size=8589934592 cluster_size=65536 lazy_refcounts=off refcount_bits=16
```

Comment: I don’t understand your question title. The body of the question seems to say that `qemu-img` can’t write to the cifs share, PERIOD. Please [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Which kernel are you running? Just wondering if it's related to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1484130

Comment: does moving the image to the mount point work? What deos qemu-img do (consult the man-page to get an idea)? Perhaps play around with `dd` to create random data and use different block sizes `bs=...`

Comment: I'm using the 4.13 kernel on ubuntu Linux version 4.13.0-21-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-037) (gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)) #24-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 18 17:29:16 UTC 2017.  Maybe the bug is relavent?

I'll try creating an image locally and moving it to cifs share and testing again.

G-Man - apologies if the question is unclear... I'm not really sure how to clarify it.  I am able to touch/edit text files on the cifs share (from my same server I am trying to use qemu on)

Thanks all

Comment: If I copy a working .qcow2 file to my cifs share /nasvirt, then edit my domain with the new source file path, I get a permission denied error when I try to start the guest.  Weird, as I'm running virsh as root.

root@host01:/var/lib/libvirt# virsh start ns01
error: Failed to start domain ns01
... -drive file=/var/lib/nasvirt/ns01/ns01.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0: Could not open '/var/lib/nasvirt/ns01/ns01.qcow2': Permission denied

Comment: its not an issue with how I setup the mount is it?:

//home-nas/vms on /var/lib/nasvirt type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=default,cache=strict,username=admin,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.159,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is perfectly clear even if the scenario is strange.

Comment: There's a lot of text in the comments that should be added to the question.

Comment: @PhilMeyerson Please add OS version details and detail logs too. Are you going to start a VM ?